# Logitech G300s disconnecting randomly

Tags: mouse, logitech-mouse

I have Ryzen 5 2600, Gigabyte 1660ti, LPX 8GB DDR4 3000Mhz, Gigabyte B450M DS3H, and Corsair VS 650 PSU. My Logitech G300s mouse is disconnecting and reconnecting randomly. Sometimes the keyboard is also gets disconnected along with the mouse. But when I changed the mouse with a cheap one, it working properly and the keyboard is also working correctly. Surprisingly my Logitech G300s are working fine in my brother's PC. I have tried changing USB settings from device manager and Power Plan Settings.

Comment: Have you tried using an alternative USB port on your machine? Have you updated all of your drivers, including the mouse firmware?

Comment: I have tried different USB port and every driver is updated.. I have checked in DriverEasy software